# How to get data for specific post id?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm using wordpress for building a site.

I have in the database a column with the id of the post and I want to use a template for all posts to get the data.

What I want to do is: if post id is the same as in the database column get the data and show it.

I'm using a sql query now, but it shows the data of all posts. How can I get the data for the specific post?

The database look like this:

```
column: wordpress_id = 275 | name = example1
column: wordpress_id = 285 | name = example2
```

275 and 285 is the id of the post in wordpress. if i say

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE wordpress_id=275";
```

in the template, it doesn't show the data of post id 285.

Comment: post the query you are using.  we need a lot more information if you are going to receive any help...  generally you can do something like this in your query to get a specific row: `SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE someId=123`

Comment: Please give more information about this. You can post your current code too.

Comment: I know that but I want to use a template for all posts. If I say WHERE Id=123 it show only the data of that id.  What I want to do is: if the post ID is the same as the ID in the database; get only the data of that ID.

Comment: If your posts are visible from the wordpress backend, and not in a custom table, then you can access posts with `WP_Query()`, but if you have custom table, then you need a custom query to fetch all your posts...

Comment: @dingo_d

The database look like this:

column: wordpress_id = 275 | name = example1
column: wordpress_id = 285 | name = example2


275 and 285 is the id of the post in wordpress. if i say 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE wordpress_id=275";      in the template


it doesn't show the data of post id 285.

Comment: Are you using WordPress default posts or custom post type?

Comment: @Nikhil custom post type

Comment: @HzrCan I've added an answer, Note: Don't use direct MySQL queries since there is methods available to get data in WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

Read this documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/

In WordPress, your posts and custom post types are stored in same table and it is not required to specify the post type. So you can use the following code to fetch post from the database using id.

```
$id = YOUR_POST_ID;
$post = get_post( $id );
```

Check the output and grab values which is needed.

Note: If you are using hooks available in WordPress, there is methods to get data from database without using normal MySQL queries.

I hope this helps.

Comment: it doesn't help; the problem is = I have a template to get data from the database. I want to use the template for all posts and not for one specific post. @Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
<?php
$id = get_the_ID();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM example WHERE wordpress_id=$id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "Example: " . $row["example1"]. "<br>";

}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```